# Pandas Crosstable is missing column description when exported to Excel

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I have a code that creates the cross table for Panels and used motors.

```
import pandas as pd

Pnl = ['Panel A','Panel A','Panel A','Panel A','Panel A','Panel B','Panel B','Panel B','Panel B','Panel C','Panel C','Panel C']
Pwr = [0.55,1,0.55,4,2.2,2.2,1,0.55,4,5,1,2.2]

df = pd.DataFrame({"Panel": Pnl, "Power" : Pwr})
df_cross = pd.crosstab(df['Panel'],df['Power'])
print(df_cross)
df_cross.to_excel('crosstable.xlsx')
```

[This is a result in the console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMfu9.png)

When I export it to Excel, the Power values are shifted to different row and column description disappears.
[This is the result table in Excel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4bDy.png)

What am I doing wrong? I exported some pivots to Excel before and no row was deleted.

Comment: What is missing?

Comment: This first row in Excel should also say 'Power'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't export to excel both `index` and `columns` `name` without manually including a new empty row.

To prevent this and export the column's name instead of the index's, get rid of the `index` name and use the `index_label` parameter:

```
df_cross.index.name = None
df_cross.to_excel('crosstable.xlsx', index_label=df_cross.columns.name)
```

Comment: This way I just replace 'Panel' for 'Power', so now I am just missing different information.

Comment: As said, no way to combine both axis names in one cell without manually including an empty row.

Comment: I don't want to combine them into one cell, I want to have a same format as in console.

Comment: Do you realize the representation in your console has a whole empty line after the `Panel` label?

Comment: Yes I realize that, this line is present in Excel when I export the pivot table, this issues is about that part missing.